# Why doesn't -w1 (wait) seem to work for nc in CentOS7?

Tags: centos

I have the following check:

```
nc -v -w 1 --send-only test.serv.com 80 &> /dev/null && echo "Online" || echo "Offline"
```

This never prints anything though. This previously worked on CentOS6, with `-z` instead of `--send-only`.

If I take off the `&> /dev/null`, it prints that the connection was made successfully:

````
Ncat: Version 6.40 ( http://nmap.org/ncat )
Ncat: Connected to 10.10.1.1:80.```
````

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, they switched to a different netcat implementation.

There are at least 5 implementations I know of:

- [GNU Netcat](http://netcat.sourceforge.net/)
- [Classic Netcat](http://nc110.sourceforge.net/)
- [Netcat6](http://netcat6.sourceforge.net/)
- [OpenBSD Netcat](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/src/usr.bin/nc/)
- [Busybox Netcat](https://busybox.net/)

All five of these support the same basic options (`-p` and `-l` for example), but beyond the most basic functionality, they all have different features (and some of them even use different option flags for the same functionality).